# Select-String to grep but just return unique groups

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file that contains very long lines. I need one piece of information from each line, and need to see the unique values. My original thought was to use Select-String and specify a regular expression with a capture group. I've looked at several other posts but none worked. Here's the quick-and-dirty C# equivalent:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"path\File.txt");
var r = new Regex("Path=\"(.*?)\"");
var matches = r.Matches(text);

var h = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    h.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}

foreach (var s in h)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

How can I do this in PowerShell?

**UPDATE:**

Testing the answers, I realized there's an additional requirement. There can be multiple matches per source line. Example:

```
Path="One" Path="Two"
Path="Two" Path="Three"
```

Results should be:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select-string -path <filepath> -pattern 'Path=\"(.*?)\"' -allmatches  |
  foreach-object {$_.matches} |
   foreach-object {$_.groups[1].value} |
    Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: Please see the update above. Also, note that the text comes from a file.

Comment: Updated for new requirements.

Comment: This worked except for the get-unique. If I replaced that with select-object -Unique it worked perfectly. Personally I find this clearer than the `[regex]` answers.

Comment: Edited to correct. Note that the backslash-escapes of the double quotes appear to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following you:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Foreach-Object { [regex]::match($_,'Path="(.*?)"').Groups[1].Value} | Select-Object -Unique
```

UPDATE:

```
PS > Select-String -Path file.txt -Pattern 'Path="([^"]+)"' -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value} | Select-Object -Unique

One
Two
Three
```

Comment: Please see the update above. And can this be done with select-string?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments :

```
${c:\silogix\t.txt} | % {[regex]::matches($_, 'Path="(.*?)"')} | % {$_.Groups[1].value} | Select-Object -Unique
```

Be careful: `${file-path}` reads the file like `Get-Content`, but `file-path` must be absolute!